# При нажатии на ссылку в другую ссылку записывается адрес

Tags: jquery

Имеется такой код:

```
<a href="#img1">
  <img src="/public/images/banners/2.jpg">
</a>
<a href="/admin/viewBanners/#_" class="lightbox" id="сюда вставить img1">
  <img src="/public/images/banners/74.jpg">
</a>
```

Как сделать, что бы при нажатии на первую ссылку считывалось img1 из href и записывалось во вторую ссылку в id

Comment: Выглядит как костыль) А для какой финальной цели приходится такое делать?)

Comment: через php вывожу список картинок и по нажатию на одну из них открывается большая картинка. Большая картинка это и есть вторая ссылка, изначально эта ссылка скрыта(картинка), потом по нажатию появляется и по нажатию пропадает

Comment: https://codepen.io/HellDRG/pen/GRKWOOK вот это, только для множества картинок нужен скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Организовать это можно примерно вот таким образом:

```js
$('.img-source').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.lightbox').attr('id', $(this).attr('href').replace('#', ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#img1" class="img-source">
  <img src="/public/images/banners/2.jpg">
</a>
<a href="/admin/viewBanners/#_" class="lightbox" id="сюда вставить img1">
  <img src="/public/images/banners/74.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде то что нужно, домой приду запущу

Comment: а что делать если первых ссылок может быть много с такими id #img1 #img2 #img3 #img4 итд

Comment: Спасибо, смог все таки решить этот вопрос